# Confused about this generics use case

Tags: java, generics

What i understand from this code is that genericDao is supposed to return  an object of type `TypeLiteral<T>` where T extends Bean.class .

```
public <T extends Bean> TypeLiteral<T> genericDao() {
        return (TypeLiteral<T>) TypeLiteral.get(Types.newParameterizedType(
                        GenericDao.class, type, getKey()));
    }
```

But shouldn't the method have been written  this way ?

```
public  TypeLiteral< T extends Bean> genericDao() {
        return (TypeLiteral<T>) TypeLiteral.get(Types.newParameterizedType(
                        GenericDao.class, type, getKey()));
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the syntax for generic methods.

The `<T extends Bean>` in the method declaration tells us that the method uses generics, and you can use `T` inside the method body as a type.

In your code, `T` has no meaning.

Answer (score 3):

For a generic method the parameterized type specification is separate from the return type. See the examples [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). For instance:

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    for (T o : a) {
        c.add(o); // Correct
    }
}
```

So this example returns void but is parameterized with `<T>`. In your case you paramterize with `<T extends Bean>` and return `TypeLiteral<T>`. In your second example the compiler would not know the type of T, as the method is not declared as a generic method but as a regular one.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into complex details of Java Language Spec, simple reason for the syntax is because the type parameter T could be used several times within the method declaration, eg:

```
public <T extends Bean> TypeLiteral<T> genericDao(T param1, T param2) {
  T localvar1;
  T localvar2;
  ...
}
```

Having to specify `T extends Bean` everytime is redundant and unecessary